# Drivers other than `pdftex.def' are not supported

Tags: pdftex

When we edit or add some word or sentence then file are run but edited or added sentence are not run, i.e. not appear in pdf file.

Comment: This question is extremely unclear.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid I'm pretty lost as well. Are you making sure you've saved the file before running `pdflatex`? Also, for some people, I understand it's necessary to close the PDF viewer first

Comment: Actually, when I have updated Windows 8.1 into windows 10 such type of problems are appearing. During the execution of tex file, it is showing that "Drivers other than `pdftex.def' are not supported". While my tex file is running but edited tex is not appearing in the pdf file. I have updated the miktex and texmaker with latest version.

Comment: @mahesh: Please edit your question to include additional information.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: **Please, include some additional information.** What distribution do you use? MikTeX or TeXlive? Which version of the distribution? And please, could you try to construct a _very small document_ that shows the issue (we usually call such document a [minimal example (link)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)). Currently nobody but you can know whether there's a typo in your code, or it is a bug in some package, or something is set up badly, or it's a bug in Windows 10 or whatever. Without getting more information, we really can't help you.

Answer (score 6):

The warning

```
Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than `pdftex.def' are not supported.
```

comes from package `epstopdf-base` (usually automatically loaded by `graphics.cfg`)
can be triggered, when package `graphics` or `graphicx` is loaded with the *wrong* driver and the file is compiled by `pdflatex`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Fix the driver options in your `.tex` file. The driver options can be omitted in many cases, because pdfTeX/luaTeX in PDF mode and XeTeX are detected automatically (`graphics.cfg`/`color.cfg`). The DVI driver default is often `dvips`.